# enable static navigation on a Samsung galaxy S2

Tags: gps, samsung-mobile

I have a Samsung Galaxy S2 and I play INGRESS and Geocaching. The S2 has a built in "static navigation disable" filter, which means that if your velocity is under a certain threshold (I think is 4Km/h) the updates in the position coming from the GPS are NOT sent to any app. The goal is to prevent your position from wandering when you are not moving but: when you are geocaching and you **walk** some meters, you want this update to appear in your GPS app.

Every single forum points to GPS Control SiRF Donate, but it was discontinued on 2012 and does not work for newer android versions.

Does anyone know about a new app or something? I did root my cellphone for testing the app so, if rooting or scripting is needed, I can go for it.

Details from the cellphone:

GT-I9100 Android 4.1.2 base-band : I9100XXMS4 Kernel : 3.0.31-1497824 dpi@DELL133#3 SMP PREEMPT Mon Dec 23 Compilation num: JZO54K.I9100XWMS3

GPS chipset, unknown (if someone provides instructions for how to get this) I will update it.

I found this other source [here](http://www.phonandroid.com/forum/tutoriel-galaxy-s2-i9100-i-9100p-passer-le-gps-en-static-fixer-le-gps-tres-rapidement-t61546.html), but I dont know what "ROM" do I have. .so not sure if it will work for me, can someone help in that direction ?

Comment: The GPS chip is a SiRFstarIV based **GSD4t**.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I cannot provide full information but I found a guy in xda-developers who sent me an already patched version of the gps.exynos4.so.
In order to use this very file your own gps.exynos4.so must have CCBBBBB5023EC7C815807D37AAC65FFB and (don't ask me why) you should has never entered recovery mode in your cellphone.

Then you simple replace the file, and make sure the permissions stay the same (rw- r-- r--).

Here's a link to the file, I cannot guaranty that it will stay there for a long time, but at least you know whats the file that need to be replaced :

https://dl.dropboxusercontent.com/u/...gps.exynos4.so

Make sure that the MD5 of the new file is: AB05F04F1CE238083DAB33BC753BCA88

Answer (score 0):

If you did not find a ready to use solution on the web, I would recommend to have a look yourself. Chances are, that this limitation is inside the kernel, the Android Framework or the (proprietary?) gps binary.

Perhaps you can narrow it down watching logcat and kmsg. If you have to run around outside to trigger it, you can easily direct them into a file. (after "adb shell" and "su" type "logcat > /data/local/tmp/myFilename01 &" or "cat /proc/kmsg > /data/local/tmp/myFilenameK01 &".

If you think it might be the Kernel, no problem, get it from opensource.samsung.com (select your device). Compiling and replacing the kernel on a S2 is quite simple. But you might need a linux environment and an appropriate toolchain, all available ready to use from the web.

If your guess is on the android framework, Xposed might be a nice solution. You can use it to overwrite certain methods. You could have a look on the aosp (Android OpenSource Project) branch for this device to find methods you are interested in.

And if you think it might be in a binary file from which you can't find the source you might be able to use the LD_PRELOAD thing to overwrite methods that might help you achive your goal.

Good Luck!